# how to render a razor partial from inside an aspx master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've just read the following article

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

it outlines an interesting technique/hack to override the "View" method to allow razor views to replace aspx views. I'm wondering if anyone has a similar override for partials?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to render the partial from within a view? If so - you shouldn't need to do anything differently. Calling Html.Partial or Html.RenderPartial from you aspx view should render a razor partial.